# How can I ignore or remove ".ipynb_checkpoints" in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tf.keras, os.walk, os.path

My code in tf.keras is given below. 
I want to retrieve a file(Xscale.npy) in each sub_directory(component_0, component_1) of model_cnn folder.

```
root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn'

    i=0
    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(root_dir):
      for d in dirs:
        print(dirs) 
        os.chdir(os.path.join(root, d))
        print(os.getcwd())
        datafile3 = './Xscale.npy'
        Xscale = np.load(datafile3)
```

The error message is,

```
['.ipynb_checkpoints', 'component_0', 'component_1']
/content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn/.ipynb_checkpoints
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-862f78aebef9> in <module>()
     57     print(os.getcwd())
     58     datafile3 = './Xscale.npy'
---> 59     Xscale = np.load(datafile3)
     60     Xtest = (Xtest0 - Xscale[0])/Xscale[1]
     61 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    426         own_fid = False
    427     else:
--> 428         fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")
    429         own_fid = True
    430 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Xscale.npy'
```

I recognize that '.ipynb_checkpoints' is the problem.
But, when I look into the folder, there is no .ipynb_checkpoints file or folder.

My drive in Colab is
[image]

My questions are

1) How can I ignore .ipynb_checkpoints when accessing a file in sub_directories?

2) Why is .ipynb_checkpoints file not visible in colab disk?

Thanks in advance,
D.-H.

Comment: the file isn't visible in the GUI because it is a dot file which means it is hidden by default. also no need to switch directories that breaks things, just feed the path to the item...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following.

1) Check if it is a hidden file

2) Not use `os.chdir` as it is not necessary.

```
root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn'
datafile3 = 'Xscale.npy'

i=0
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(root_dir):
    for d in dirs:
        if not d.startswith('.'):
            dir_path = os.path.join(root, d)
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, datafile3)
            Xscale = np.load(file_path)
```

There are more elegant ways to do this in terms of getting absolute file paths but I wanted to minimize the amount of code changed.

An alternative method uses `pathlib`.

```
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn'
datafile3 = 'Xscale.npy'

i=0
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(root_dir):
    for d in dirs:
        if not d.startswith('.'):
            fp = Path(root) / d / datafile3
            Xscale = np.load(str(fp))
```

Comment: If possible, could you show me your more elegant way to do this?

Comment: added the cleaner way to do it which uses `pathlib`

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. This might be happening because during the upload, it is also uploading the `.ipynb_checkpoint` which is a hidden folder. A fix for this is that you can manually delete the folder using

`rmdir /content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn/.ipynb_checkpoints` in a cell just before executing the code you mention.

Comment: This helps but you need to write it as follows: rmdir /content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn/".ipynb_checkpoints"

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following solution in this [link](https://gist.github.com/ArnoutDevos/46704443f2456ded8da2c3266b216cd4).

Use the command -

```
rm -rf `find -type d -name .ipynb_checkpoints`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` with `rglob` for a cleaner code.

```py
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/DeepCID/model_cnn'
root = Path(root_dir)
# parent dir must not start with dot
for datafile in root.rglob('[!.]*/Xscale.npy'):
  print(datafile)  # or np.load(datafile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/models/dataset2/train/images/.ipynb_checkpoints.csv'

if os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.remove(file_path)
    print("File deleted successfully.")
else:
    print("File not found.")
```

```
import shutil
import os

folder_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/models/dataset2/train/images/.ipynb_checkpoints'

if os.path.exists(folder_path):
    shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    print("Folder deleted successfully.")
else:
    print("Folder not found.")
```